# Output from servlet to JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am passing parameters from JSP page *calendar.jsp* to a servlet *connect.java*.
In the Java class I am passing a query from a database. It retrievs data fine but I need it to print the result back to the JSP page.

I tried the following code but with an error at `out.println()`.

```
@WebServlet("/calendar")
public class Connect extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                throws ServletException, IOException {
        String fromDate = request.getParameter("fromDate");
        String toDate = request.getParameter("toDate");
        System.out.println("fromDate---->"+fromDate);
        System.out.println("toDate---->"+toDate);
        String query = "SELECT action_time,user_action,user_ip,user_id FROM ksdi.login_detail where (action_time, action_time) OVERLAPS (DATE '"
                    + fromDate+ "',DATE '"+ toDate+ "'+ integer '1')" +
                    " order by action_time desc";

        Connection conn = null;
        PreparedStatement statement = null;
        ResultSet resultSet = null;
        try {
            conn = ConnectionUtil.getConnection();
            statement = conn.prepareStatement(query);
            resultSet = statement.executeQuery();

            if (resultSet.next()) {
                while (resultSet.next()) {
                    String action_time=resultSet.getString("action_time");
                    String user_action=resultSet.getString("user_action");
                    String user_ip=resultSet.getString("user_ip");
                    String user_id=resultSet.getString("user_id");
                    System.out.println((action_time) + " " + (user_action) + " "+(user_ip) + " "+(user_id) + " ");

                    response.setContentType("text/html");  
                    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();  
                    out.println("action time"+((ResultSet) request).getString("action_time")+"<br />");  
                    RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("calendar.jsp");  
                    view.forward(request,response);         
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("not found");
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new ServletException("DB interaction failed", e);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (resultSet != null) try { resultSet.close(); } catch (SQLException ignore) {}
            if (statement != null) try { statement.close(); } catch (SQLException ignore) {}
            if (conn != null) try { conn.close(); } catch (SQLException ignore) {}
        }
    }

}
```

Here is my JSP file:

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%  String path = request.getContextPath();%>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />

    <script src="<%=path%>/js/calendar.js"></script>
    <link href="<%=path %>/css/calendar.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<form action="calendar">
            <div class="container">
            From:<input  name="fromDate" type="text" class="calendarSelectDate" />
            To: <input   name="toDate"   type="text" class="calendarSelectDate" />
            <input type="submit" name="b1" value="Go">
        </div>          
<div id="calendarDiv"></div>


</form> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: post your exception stack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) In your servlet code you are doing it wrong. You should **either** output using PrintWriter's `println()` **or** use RequestDispatcher's `forward()` method. But **NOT both in the same servlet's method**.

Quote from here: [**What is a request dispatcher and how do I use it?**](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/what-is-a-request-dispatcher-and-how-do-i-use-it.html)

> Unlike the case with the 'include', the **'forward' discards the
>   previous output that Servlet had written to the response**.

See the examples in the above mentioned page.

And if you choose to use `forward()` then to pass the data previously retieved from your database, you can store that data in the request scope, i.e. set the request attributes, like

```
request.setAttribute("actionTime", action_time);
```

Of course you must do it **before** calling `forward()`!

Then in your JSP you can output that data using [Expression Languge](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info), like this:
*test.jsp*

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test Page</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Testing the passed values</h1>
    <p>Action time: ${actionTime}</p>
    <!-- same way for other data -->
</body>
</html>
```

2) Another issue, in your servlet code there is a line that has this:
`((ResultSet) request).getString("action_time")`

Neaither [ServletRequest](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html) nor [HttpServletRequest](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html) has the method `getString()`. Although *ResultSet* has such method, but, in your case, it is pointless and wrong to cast a request to *ResultSet*.

---

P.S.
[Using scriplets in JSP is discouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3180202/814702)

Comment: RequestDispatcher is only passing one result to jsp but i have multiple results that i am fetching from database///

Comment: @IshanKaushik Request dispatcher **forwards the request, not the result**. And in the _request_, you can set as many attributes as you like. Plus you can put all the results in some JavaBean, using **DTO** pattern (read here: [**Data Transfer Object**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Transfer_Object)). Also read the article I gave the link for in my answer. Plus read some tutorials, like [Beginning & Intermediate Servlet & JSP Tutorials](http://courses.coreservlets.com/Course-Materials/csajsp2.html), and [Java Servlets](http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/JavaServlets.html).

Answer (score 0):

The could is casting the returned `HttpServletRequest` request to a `ResultSet`, I think it should use the `ResultSet`'s `getString` method with no casting.

```
   PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();  
   out.println("action time"+ resultSet.getString("action_time") + "<br />");
```

Answer (score 0):

Well **set the values you fetch into httprequest** like this in the servlet

PS: i have commented unnecessary lines

```
   //response.setContentType("text/html");  
     //PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();  
    // out.println("action time"+((ResultSet) request).getString("action_time")+"<br />"); 

        request.setAttribute("action_time",action_time);
        request.setAttribute("user_action",user_action);
        request.setAttribute("user_ip",user_ip);
        request.setAttribute("user_id",user_id);


     RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("calendar.jsp");  
    view.forward(request,response);
```

And in **calendar.jsp** to which you forward , access the values by

```
<%= request.getAttribute("action_time")%>
<%= request.getAttribute("user_action")%>
<%= request.getAttribute("user_ip")%>
<%= request.getAttribute("user_id")%>
```

Comment: What? Are you trying to set request attributes **after forwarding** to JSP? It is wrong. Please correct your answer

Comment: That's what I thought. No problem ))